# Smote algorithm

Tags: machine-learning, classification, smote

When our dataset has 5 or more attributes, what will be the method of producing a new sample with Smote algorithm?
How will the Euclidean distance with 5 or more attributes be calculated?

Comment: Why is 5 or more attributed (variables) an issue? Euclidean distance can be computed for arbitrary dimensions.

Answer (score 1):

Euclidean distance $d$ between vectors $x,y\in\mathbb R^n$ is:

$$
d(x,y)=
\sqrt{
\sum_{i=1}^n \bigg(
x_i-y_i
\bigg)^2
}
$$

If the dimension is $2$, that’s the formula. If the dimension is $5$, that’s the formula. If the dimension is $1234567890987654321$, that’s the formula.

[However, SMOTE tends to be portrayed as a solution to something that isn’t such a problem.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/357466)

Comment: I suspect SMOTE is useful for classification techniques where cost-sensitive learning is not readily available and where there is no direct means of controlling over-fitting, which I suspect was true for Naive Bayes, individual decision trees and RIPPER implementations at the time the paper was written.  I don't think it ought to be used with modern methods, like the SVM, which supports both cost-sensitive learning and regularization (to avoid over-fitting).